# Rails Delayed job: job is not running from the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am starting delayed job with command `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job -n 5 start`.delayed job is performing heavy database operation and each delayed job process is taking almost 15 minutes to complete.

For testing purpose i ran 3 jobs simultaneously of of which two jobs processed successfully and remaining 1 job is not processing. This job is in the delayed job table but still it is not running.

```
***********************delayed job log********************************

er(delayed_job.4 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:1524)] Starting job worker
I, [2015-12-15T05:36:26.154690 #1498]  INFO -- : 2015-12-15T05:36:26+0000: [Worker(delayed_job.0 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:1498)] Job QrCodeGenerator (id=1) RUNNING
I, [2015-12-15T05:36:26.229763 #1504]  INFO -- : 2015-12-15T05:36:26+0000: [Worker(delayed_job.1 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:1504)] Job QrCodeGenerator (id=2) RUNNING
I, [2015-12-15T05:36:41.322419 #1510]  INFO -- : 2015-12-15T05:36:41+0000: [Worker(delayed_job.2 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:1510)] Job QrCodeGenerator (id=3) RUNNING
I, [2015-12-15T05:50:51.485299 #1510]  INFO -- : 2015-12-15T05:50:51+0000: [Worker(delayed_job.2 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:1510)] Job QrCodeGenerator (id=3) COMPLETED after 850.1627
I, [2015-12-15T05:50:51.488960 #1510]  INFO -- : 2015-12-15T05:50:51+0000: [Worker(delayed_job.2 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:1510)] 1 jobs processed at 0.0012 j/s, 0 failed
I, [2015-12-15T05:50:59.107773 #1498]  INFO -- : 2015-12-15T05:50:59+0000: [Worker(delayed_job.0 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:1498)] Job QrCodeGenerator (id=1) COMPLETED after 872.9529
I, [2015-12-15T05:50:59.108821 #1498]  INFO -- : 2015-12-15T05:50:59+0000: [Worker(delayed_job.0 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:1498)] 1 jobs processed at 0.0011 j/s, 0 failed

*********************remaining entry with Delayed::Job.all*************

2.0.0-p598 :001 > Delayed::Job.all
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 2, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/struct:QrCodeGenerator\nclient: !ruby/obj...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2015-12-15 08:17:22", locked_at: "2015-12-15 05:36:26", failed_at: nil, locked_by: "delayed_job.1 host:ip-172-31-6-58 pid:1504", queue: nil, created_at: "2015-12-15 05:36:23", updated_at: "2015-12-15 08:17:26">]>
```

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: Is it still in the sidekiq queue ? Check /sidekiq for more info.

If it failed, and is retrying, you can check the errors in log/sidekiq.log

Comment: I am not using sidekiq . i am using delayed job . i saw the delayed job log and its not failed.

Comment: not processing have many meanings can you please show the log

Comment: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems this might help you to understand

Comment: My bad, read it to quick, can you also show us the remaining job entries with Delayed::Job.all

Comment: @all - please see edited question.

Comment: @user2274074 your jobs are not added in the data base ? only showing one job

Comment: @RajarshiDas - it is showing only one job because remaining two jobs have been completed.

Comment: did you set Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false all jobs should be shown can you try worker for debug as it is not getting error `worker = Delayed::Worker.new({quiet: false}) worker.start`

Comment: no i have set it to true. Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = true

Comment: Please make it false and debug it and put the output here it will be good for you to track the error